# Using for loop to extract items from .RData files into an empty vector?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a series of tests each with its own .RData file. I am trying to use a for loop in R to extract a particular variable from each file. The code I currently have is:

```
setwd("C:/Users/c7271616/test files directory/") #File where test data files are
schedule <- list.files(pattern = ".RData") #list of files 
p_inputs<- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(schedule)) # empty vector to store results

for (i in 1:length(schedule)){
  load(paste(getwd(),"/",schedule[i],sep = ""))
  p <- as.numeric(P1)
  p_inputs[i] <- p
}
p_inputs
```

The result is an vector where the first n items are 0 then one value of P has been appended on the end of the mostly empty vector.

```
   0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 
0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
0.000    0.000 6437.887
```

How can I alter the code so the "p" values are stored in the empty vector? I know the loop is looping through all the files as I have experimented with a `print(p)` in the loop and it lists all the values but does not store them in the vector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by using a counter variable like so:

```
setwd("C:/Users/c7271616/OneDrive - Leeds Beckett University/QUB Data/Gowbusk Farm/QUB Summarys/")
schedule <- list.files(pattern = ".RData")

#p_inputs <- data.frame(mode = "numeric", length = length(schedule))
p_inputs<- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(schedule))
test_ids<- vector(mode = "character", length = length(schedule))
counter <- 1

for (i in 1:length(schedule)){
  load(paste(getwd(),"/",schedule[i],sep = ""))
  p <- P1
  p_inputs[counter] <- p
  test_id <- paste(test_date, duration)
  test_ids[counter] <- test_id
  counter <- counter +1
}

p_inputs
```